# Webflux webclient and generic types

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-webflux

I am trying to build a generic class that will consume a REST API. The API returns lists of objects depending on the url.

I have built a Generic class

```
public class RestConsumer<T> {
    WebClient client;

    public RestConsumer(){
        //Initialize client
    }

    public List<T> getList(String relativeUrl){
        try{
            return client
                .get()
                .uri(relativeUrl)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>> (){}
                .block()
        catch(Exception e){}
}
```

}

The problem is that T is replaced by Object at compilation time and the whole thing returns a List of LinkedHashMap instead of a List of T. I tried lots of workarounds but had no luck. Any clue?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 20):

I encountered the same problem and in order to work I added ParameterizedTypeReference as a parameter for that function.

```
public <T> List<T> getList(String relativeUrl, 
                           ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>> typeReference){
    try{
        return client
            .get()
            .uri(relativeUrl)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(typeReference)
            .block();
    } catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

And call that function with

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyClass>> typeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyClass>>(){};
List<MyClass> strings = getList(relativeUrl, typeReference);
```

Comment: Very clever answer!

Comment: This is great. It worked. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you are using kotlin, key is to use reified to preserve the class type from generic types on the calling field.

Here is the code:

```
inline fun <reified T> getMonoResult(uriParam: String): T? = client
    .get()
    .uri(uriParam)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(T::class.java)
    .block(Duration.ofSeconds(1))

inline fun <reified T> getFluxResult(uriParam: String): MutableList<T>? = client
    .get()
    .uri(uriParam)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(T::class.java)
    .collectList()
    .block(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a class (say CollectionT) and add List of T as an attribute there. Then You can easily cast it into Mono, which on, .map(x -> x.getList()) will return a Mono of List of T. It also makes your code look more non-blocking by avoiding, .block()

Here goes the code: ->

```
public class CollectionT {

   private List<T> data;

   //getters
   public List<T> getData(){
    return data;
   }

   //setters
     ...
}

public class RestConsumer<T> {
    WebClient client = WebClient.create();

    public RestConsumer(){
        //Initialize client
    }

        public List<T> getList(String relativeUrl){

                return client
                    .get()
                    .uri(relativeUrl)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(CollectionT.class)
                    .map(x -> x.getData());

    }
}
```

Comment: The above example does not compile